# Mensa online IQ test question - visual analogy with squares and circles

Tags: visual, pattern, explanation

I took a [Mensa online IQ test](https://www.mensa.lu/en/mensa/online-iq-test/online-iq-test.html) and encountered this question which I wasn't able to do:

[image: IQ test with 4 pictures and 5 options, 2 gaps to fill]

This question is basically a visual analogy, where the first picture is to the second picture as the third picture is to the fourth picture. This question is also found on these websites: https://sifter.org/iqtest/ and http://nzlweb.com/. I know the answer is A and D but I cannot find a pattern that explains *why* the answer is A and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the answers A and D, it's fairly simple to describe the rules:

> The first and third pictures both have a circle, a square, and a line shape inside. Notice that the order of the two outer shapes (the circle and square) are reversed, and the inner shape is also rotated 180 degrees (or mirrored across a NW-SE diagonal). Then it suffices to find two shapes among the choices that exhibit the same relationship (two outer shapes appear in reverse order, and an inner shape is rotated). The choices A and D form such a pair, because the enclosing square and triangle are reversed, and the inner shape is rotated 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lazy answer, but according to http://nzlweb.com/, this is what the explanation says:

> Here the answers A and D are correct. The given symbols consist of two circles, two squares and two half-squares. The answers A and D are similar, but the circles are replaced by triangles.

Hope this helped.